# Make iTerm2 ignore all terminal control sequences

Tags: linux, shell, iterm2

I'm debugging a command line tool that manipulates the terminal (e.g. clears the screen). Problem: I want to see what is output right before the "clear screen", but, well, the screen immediately clears.

How can I configure iTerm2 (or the command line) so that control sequences are just printed out? In other words, how can I make my session into a dumb typewriter?